# JS, issue running hover video playback functions independently on multiple cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, backend

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"> 
  <title>Game Cards App</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entertainment-events-hobbies/24/card-game-cards-hold-512.png">
  
<style>

#main-content {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(7, 50, 22, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255) 100%);
  animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
 
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}



.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6); 
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), transparent, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5)); 
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #483D8B, #301934, #483D8B, #301934);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

}
.card__back span {
  font-weight: bold; /* Metni kalın yap */
  color: white; /* Beyaz renk */
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 8px; 
}

.tm-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  
}

.tm-letter {
 
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10%, 40%, 60%, 90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#m-letter {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
    left: 50%; /* Orta konumu */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%; /* Eğer bir daire şeklinde efekt isteniyorsa */
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8); 
    filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5); 
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
    z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
  
}


body.hoverEffect {
      background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
}

#gameCard { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 
    0 0 50px 10px #FFD700,  
    0 0 100px 20px #0000FF, 
    0 0 150px 30px #000033; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);  
    color:#FFD700;   
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid #FFD700; 
}

#gameCardLink span {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}

#gameCardLink span:last-child {
  font-size: 0.79em; 
  vertical-align: super; 
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}


#loading-animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image:url();
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover ;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
 }

.loader {

  border-top: 9px solid #00a2ed;
  border-radius: 80%;
  width: 12vw; 
  height: 12vw; 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 44%; 
  top: 46%; /
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); /* Yuvarlak halkanın tam ortasında olması için bu dönüşümü kullanın. */
  }

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

</style> 
</head>



<body>

<div id="loading-animation">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-content">

  <div class="tm-container">
    <div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
    <div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
  </div>


<audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/321/321114_2776777-lq.ogg" type="audio/wav">
</audio>

<main>
   <div id="gameCardLink">
      <span>G</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>m</span>
      <span>e</span>
      <span> </span> <!-- Boşluk eklemek için span ekledik -->
      <span> </span>
      <span>C</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>r</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span> </span>
      <span>s</span>
      <span>®</span>
   </div>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>


<ul>
  <li id='spider' class="card" >
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
  
      
      <iframe class="frame" 
      width="225"
      height="340"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
        <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
         <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
 
  <li id='batman' class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
         <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
        <p class="card__num">2</p>
      </div>
      
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>

      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>771 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li id='guard' class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp12279011.jpg" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
        <p class="card__num">3</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
   
  
  <li id='shazam' class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
       <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
        <p class="card__num">4</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
         <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li id='flash' class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
        <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
        <p class="card__num">5</p>
        </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
        
     
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li id='strange' class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
        <p class="card__num">6</p>
         </div>
        <iframe class="frame" 
        width="225"
        height="340"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
        title="YouTube video player"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
        allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
        
      
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
          <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
        <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>


<script>
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
   // if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();
  
</script>



<script>
<!-- HOVER FOR TRAILER -->

var hoverTimeout;

function onHover() {
    const currentCard = $(this); 

    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
        currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
        var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
        currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src", src);

     
        currentCard.find('.iframe').on('click', function() {
            $(this).requestFullscreen();
        });

    }, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
 
}
function onHoverTime() {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds

    $(this).find('.card__front').show();
    $(this).find('.iframe').hide();
    var src = $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src");
    if (src) {
        $(this).find('.iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
    }
};


function setupHoverEffect(cardId) {
  console.log(`setupHoverEffect function is called for ${cardId}`);
  $(`#${cardId}`).hover(function() {
    // Call the existing onHover function when the mouse hovers over the card
    onHover.call(this);
  }, function() {
    // Call the existing onHoverTime function when the mouse leaves the card
    onHoverTime.call(this);
  });
}

setupHoverEffect("batman");
setupHoverEffect("flash");
setupHoverEffect("spider");
setupHoverEffect("shazam");
setupHoverEffect("flash");
setupHoverEffect("strange");



</script>



<script>
var cardFlags = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var flipSound = document.getElementById("flipSound");
  $(".card__front").click(function() {

    flipSound.currentTime = 0;
    flipSound.play();

  });

  
  $(".card").click(function() {
    var card = $(this);
    var cardId = card.find(".card__num").text();

    
    // Check if the card is not already flipping to avoid multiple flips
    if (!card.hasClass('flipping')) {
      card.addClass('flipping');

      // Check if the front side is facing the viewer
      if (!card.hasClass("flipped")) {
       


        if (!cardFlags[cardId]) {
          startAnimation(div); 

          cardFlags[cardId] = true; 
          card.addClass("flipped");
        }
        
        // Adding canvas to back-side 
        var div = document.querySelector('.flipped .card__flipper.active .card__back');
        var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('p5Canvas')[0];
        if (div && canvas) {
          div.appendChild(canvas);
          canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        }
      } else {
       

        card.removeClass("flipped");
        
      }

      setTimeout(function() {
        card.removeClass('flipping');
      }, 1000); 
    }
  });

  // Prevent sound on back side click
  $(".card__back").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

</script>


<script>
    // Body's hoover effect
    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        document.body.classList.add("hoverEffect");
    });

    document.getElementById("gameCardLink").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        document.body.classList.remove("hoverEffect");
    });
</script>




<script>

// Portal effect

</script>



<script>
// Hiding and showing of loading animation
  function hideLoadingAnimation() {

  var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
  var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
  loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
  mainContent.style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function() {

  hideLoadingAnimation();
};

</script>



<script> 
    // The conditions of the hover function.
    $('.card').on( "mouseenter", onHover).on( "mouseleave", onHoverTime );
    
    // hover events removing and assigning
    $(document.body).on('click', function(){
        if ($("#batman").off( "mouseenter", onHover)){
            $('#batman, #flash').hover(onHover, onHoverTime);
            console.log('yes');
            } })
            
         // overlap boundary conditions for hover on off
    $(".card").click(function(){
    let cord = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[1].style.transform; 
    [cx,cy,...rest]= cord.slice(12).split('px, ');
    console.log(`cx: ${cx}, cy: ${cy}`);
    if ((cy<=300)&&(cy>=100)||((cy>(-300))&&(cy<(-60)))){

        $("#batman").off( "mouseenter", onHover);
        $("#flash").off( "mouseenter", onHover);
        
        console.log('offed');
        let hoverTimeout;
    }
    else{
        console.log('on');
        $('#batman, #flash').hover(onHover, onHoverTime);
    }
    
});     
                
</script>

    
</html>
```

I currently have 6 cards with ids: `spider`, `batman`, `guard`, `shazam`, `flash`, `strange`. (I plan to increase the number) For these cards, I have common `onHover()` and `onHoverTime()` functions that play video trailers with hover and reset them. I want it to work independently for each card.
If I need to give a little more detail, I can say that the trailer is played when you wait 5 seconds with the mouse on the front of each card, but the longer you wait on a card, the more the trailer progresses on that card when the hover event occurs on another card. So they work as a whole.

However, what I want is for each card's hover trailer functions to work card-specific and not affect each other. (The trailer should restart from 0:00 on every hover event of each card.)

I thought adding of the following approach but it doesn't work the way I want:

```
function setupHoverEffect(cardId) {
  console.log(`setupHoverEffect function is called for ${cardId}`);
  $(`#${cardId}`).hover(function() {
    // Call the existing onHover function when the mouse hovers over the card
    onHover.call(this);
  }, function() {
    // Call the existing onHoverTime function when the mouse leaves the card
    onHoverTime.call(this);
  });
}
setupHoverEffect("spider");
setupHoverEffect("batman");
setupHoverEffect("guard");
setupHoverEffect("shazam");
setupHoverEffect("flash");
setupHoverEffect("strange");
```

Additionally, I thought it wouldn't be unmanageable if the number of cards increased so much. It may not be correct to repeat setupHoverEffect() for new cards added. How can I solve this problem?

**The link of full code:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ptX0FanoKVRUC6ni5J7_2TYUNyYuNEl_/view

**visual representation of the problem:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum amount necessary to show the issue (a [mre]) and clearly state what is meant by "didn't work" (what did you expect to happen, but did not; what happened that you did not expect to). Use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make a runnable snippet of code.

Comment: `I want it to work independently for each card` Is this the problem?  Can you please explain further?

Comment: @James,I tried to detail it a little more, can you take a look again?

Comment: "batman" starts playback at 2:00 instead of 0:00 after hovering over spiderman until 2:00.  Is this the problem?

Comment: @James, Yes, this is a problem. It was supposed to start at 0:00 in Batman. The trailer should restart from 0:00 on every hover event of each card.

Comment: When I hover on any of your cards, I do not see any video being displayed. Are you sure the hover is triggering any action in your current example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many issues happening, but I will try to address the most important ones. First thing I notice is that all the videos are set to be autoplay by default, so they all run when the page is loaded:

```
<iframe class="frame" 
      width="225"
      height="340"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
      allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
```

In the above code, see that there is query params in the src attribute `autoplay=1`, we should first remove them from all the iframes.

The next problem is that you query the DOM wrong:

```
function onHover() {
    const currentCard = $(this); 

    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
        currentCard.find('.iframe').show();
        var src = currentCard.find('.iframe').attr("src");
...
```

The class `.iframe` doesn't exist, since you assigned the iframes with `.frame` class instead. But to fix this, we can just select the DOM by its tag name, e.g.:

```
currentCard.find('iframe').show();
```

And then, since we have removed the autoplay query params, we need to readd them when `hover` event happens, we can trigger the play by appending `autoplay=1` to the query params, but when `hover` event happens like this inside the `onHover()` function:

```
currentCard.find('iframe').attr("src", src + '&autoplay=1');
```

Then finally, we need to fix the `clearTimeout`, it seems like the `setTimeout`s are triggered multiple times, i'm not sure why, but basically we can store the `timeout` id to an object so that we can store and clear all of them:

```
var hoverTimeout = {}; // an object to store timeout id
```

And then update the `onHover()` function:

```
function onHover() {
  const currentCard = $(this);

  if (hoverTimeout[currentCard.attr('id')] === undefined) {
    hoverTimeout[currentCard.attr('id')] = []; // initialize timeout id array according to element id
  }

  hoverTimeout[currentCard.attr('id')].push(setTimeout(() => {
    currentCard.find('.card__front').hide();
    currentCard.find('iframe').show();
    var src = currentCard.find('iframe').attr("src");
    currentCard.find('iframe').attr("src", src + '&autoplay=1');

    currentCard.find('iframe').on('click', function() {
      $(this).requestFullscreen();
    });

  }, 5000)); // 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)
}
```

Finally, we can update the `onHoverTime` function to this, so we can clear the timeout ids correctly:

```
function onHoverTime() {
  while (hoverTimeout[$(this).attr('id')].length > 0) {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimeout[$(this).attr('id')][0]); // Clear the timeout to prevent actions if the user moves away before 5 seconds
    hoverTimeout[$(this).attr('id')].shift();
  }

  $(this).find('.card__front').show();
  $(this).find('iframe').hide();
  var src = $(this).find('iframe').attr("src");
  if (src) {
    $(this).find('iframe').attr("src", src.replace('?autoplay=1', ''));
  }
}
```

[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damzaky/bLovwqnm/).